# How to receive only actual data from a socket

Tags: java, sockets

i am sending 20 bytes of data from my udpserver to a client in java. At the client side i am receiving like this

```
byte[] buf = new byte[25];
final DatagramPacket recv = new DatagramPacket(buf,25);
String data = new String(recv.getData());
```

when i print data it is printing additional things. How can i only get my actual data. Please suggest.

Comment: *"i am sending 20 bytes of data" and you're reading `25`...

Comment: @RemyLebeau Then one would assume that they aren't reading the data from the buffer correctly then - the point was to point out the discrepancy between what they were writing and reading in hopes it would prompt them to investigate their issue further ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending 20 bytes, but you are allocating a receive buffer that can receive up to 25 bytes. The received datagram can be smaller, but you need to take the actual received length into account when constructing the `String`, eg:

```
String data = new String(recv.getData(), 0, recv.getLength());
```